# Update "keyword" to "text" field type of an index for inexact words matching in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

```
{
        "myindex": {
            "mappings": {
                "properties": {
                    "city": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to update by using below PUT request on the index, but still getting the above ouput of _mapping

```
{
        "_doc" : {
            "properties" : {
                "city" : {"type" : "text"}
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not able to query with inexact words because its type is "keyword", for the below the actual value in record is "Mumbai"

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "city": {
                        "query": "Mumbi",
                        "minimum_should_match": "10%"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the mapping you shared 'city' will be stored both as 'text' & 'keyword'. 'city' is  text representation while city.keyword is the keyword representation.

Comment: @SahilGupta then why the above query does not return the record?

Comment: You intend to use fuzzy search .... instead of minimum_should_match use "fuzziness": <number>

Comment: @SahilGupta I tried "fuzzy": {"city": "Mumbi"}, but it does not return value..But I wanted to use minimum_should_match..so that i can match based on %..Like if it matches 80% then return the record

Comment: Read https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html & https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html

Comment: There is surely a difference b/w your intent of 10% and min_should_match 10%. It would be really helpful if you share some examples of your requirements. That will help in reaching to the result faster.

Comment: @SahilGupta return all results if city's value matches to atleast 10%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220126/discussion-between-sahil-gupta-and-happy).

Comment: @SahilGupta can a match query match extra word?
e.g "bsf chhawla camp gate"
should match with "bsf chhawla camp playground"?

Comment: Yes if the field is a 'text' & 'no' if it is a keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below mapping (What is shared in the question) will store 'city' as text and 'city.keyword' as a keyword.

```
{
        "myindex": {
            "mappings": {
                "properties": {
                    "city": {
                        "type": "text",   // ==========> Store city as text
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",  // =========> store city.keyword as a keyword
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

your's is the use case of **Fuzzy search** and not **minimum_should_match**.

**ES Docs for Fuzzy Search:** https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-fuzzy-search

**Try below query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "city": {
        "query": "mubai",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: The fuzzy query you tried didn't work as that will not analyze search text before analysis, hence even the case normalization won't happen in that case.

Answer (score 1):

**minimum_should_match**

> Minimum number of clauses that must match for a document to be returned

It signifies the percentage of clauses not the percentage of the string. Go through [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html) documentation to frame the query to get the expected results. Invalid queries return invalid results.